# How do I restrict open(...) to a directory?

Tags: ruby, file, security

I use the `open` command to open either a HTTP address or a file on my filesystem. Is it possible to restrict this command to a specific directory o that passing a path like `../../etc/passwd` isn't possible?

I know that in PHP you can use `open_basedir` directive to jail a user to a directory. Is there something similar to secure the `open` command?

Comment: Directory and file access control should be done on the OS level, not in code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that but you have to check the path to make sure it doesn't point outside your desired sandbox. `open` won't do it for you.

Look at [`File.realpath`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-realpath). It resolves `..` components in the path leaving you with the real path being requested. That path must exist or `realpath` will raise an exception, which is your first hint that you can't serve the file. You'll need to rescue `Errno::ENOENT`:

```
File.realpath('/usr/bin') # => "/usr/bin"
File.realpath('/tmp') # => "/private/tmp"

File.realpath('/foobar') 
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /foobar
```

Then you can check using a simple regex to make sure the resulting path is anchored in the area or areas you allow. Here's an example of the code.

```
SHARED_PATH_REGEXP = /\A#{ Regexp.escape(File.realpath('/path/to/shared/content')) }/i

def is_shared_path?(requested_path)
  real_requested_path = File.realpath(requested_path)
  !!real_requested_path[SHARED_PATH_REGEXP]
rescue Errno::ENOENT
  false
end

path_received('/etc/passwd') # => false
path_received(SHARED_PATH_REGEXP + '/foo.html') # => true
```

`Regexp.escape` is useful for preprocessing the file string so the regular expression engine does a literal check:

```
Regexp.escape('/usr/bin')  # => "/usr/bin"
Regexp.escape('../../public')  # => "\\.\\./\\.\\./public"
```